# Clicking with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I currently have a code which basically does a few clicks on a website...the code works fine but for some weird reason I can't seem to be able to use Firefox while the automation process is going on. is there a way to stop is ?

i.e. be able to use another Firefox window while having the process run

```
my_file = open("links.txt", "r")
for url in my_file:
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.popover').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.faux_field').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.apply').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.click-to-esign').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that particular instance locks files. To do that you need separate file set. Good news is that for Firefox there is profile, and profile manager utility. Please visit [this](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/) page to see more information about dealing with selenium and Firefox profiles